# Cannot delete files (on a ReFS volume, with leading and trailing periods)

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-server-2016, refs

I have a few thousand files (14,000) on my Windows machine, all named <kbd>`.TARDIRPERMS.`</kbd> that i cannot delete:

[image]

I can see them in Windows Explorer, and on the command line, but neither can delete the files.

Obviously i don't know the cause, but some interesting points that may be relevant are:

- It's a ReFS volume (meaning i can't `chkdsk` it)
- the files are **start** and **end** with a period (*i.e.* U+002E FULL STOP)
- i've tried deleting the parent (and parents parent) folder - same result
- i've tried `del /S /F /Q *` - same result
- i've tried `del ".tardirperms."` - same result
- i've tried [`del "\?.TARDIRPERMS."`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4075753/12597) - same result
- i've tried [`rd /s "\?UTZOO"`](https://blog.dotsmart.net/2008/06/12/solved-cannot-read-from-the-source-file-or-disk/) - same result
- i've tried [`PS D:\Torrents> Remove-Item` \?\D:\Torrents\UTZOO `-Recurse`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64851490/12597) - same result
- i've tried `del *.tardirperms.` - same result
- i've tried `del *.tardi*` - same result

[image]

Comment: How about `del *.tardirperms.` or `del *.tardi*`? Another possibility: boot another OS *via* USB, e.g., WinRE or Linux (see https://www.paragon-software.com/business/refs-linux/#), and delete from there.

Comment: I doubt other operating systems understand ReFS.

Comment: Maybe WSL could help. Otherwise, programming a specialized application to remove the files is always possible.

Comment: @IanBoyd, if you check the link above, it shows the Paragon proprietary ReFS handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short Version

`>del /S /Q "\\?\D:\Torrents\UTZOO\*"`

For file I/O, the **\\?\** prefix to a path string tells the Windows APIs to disable all string parsing and to send the string that follows it [straight to the file system.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)

### Long Version

The filename `.TARDIRPERMS.` is a valid NT filename, but it is not a valid Win32 filename. You can tell the Win32 functions to ignore the normal Win32 naming limitations, and pass the filename, as is, to the corresponding underlying **NtCreateFile** function, by prefixing the filename with `\\?\`:

- **Fails**: `D:\Torrents\UTZOO\.TARDIRPERMS.`
- **Good**: `\\?\D:\Torrents\UTZOO\.TARDIRPERMS.`

Microsoft gives a general summary of various reasons you wouldn't be able to delete a file in an article title [You can't delete a file or a folder on an NTFS file system volume](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/cannot-delete-file-folder-on-ntfs-file-system).

Of interest to me is Cause #6:

> ### Cause 6: The file name includes an invalid name in the Win32 name space
>
> You can't delete a file if the file name includes an invalid name. For example, the file name has a trailing space or a trailing period, or the file name is made up of a space only. To resolve this issue, use a tool that uses the appropriate internal syntax to delete the file. You can use the `"\\?\"` syntax with some tools to operate on these files. Here's an example:
>
> ```
> del "\\?\c:\<path_to_file_that contains a trailing space.txt>"
> ```
>
> The cause of this issue is similar to [Cause 4](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/cannot-delete-file-folder-on-ntfs-file-system#cause-4-files-exist-in-paths-that-are-deeper-than-max_path-characters). If you use typical Win32 syntax to open a file that has trailing spaces or trailing periods in its name, the trailing spaces or periods are stripped before the actual file is opened. For example, you have two files in the same folder named `AFile.txt` and `AFile.txt` , note the space after the file name. If you try to open the second file by using standard Win32 calls, you open the first file instead. Similarly, if you have a file whose name is just a space character and you try to open it by using standard Win32 calls, you open the file's parent folder instead. In this situation, if you try to change security settings on these files, you either may not be able to do so, or you may unexpectedly change the settings on different files. If this behavior occurs, you may think that you have permission to a file that actually has a restrictive ACL.

So the trick was:

```
>del /S /Q "\\?\D:\Torrents\UTZOO\*"
```

Where

- **`/S`**: Delete specified files from all subdirectories.
- **`/Q`**: Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to delete on global wildcard

And using the `\\?\` prefix tells Win32 to bypass the typical Win32 name checks that are done when a file is created or deleted.